# Document keydown event propagates to a input child with stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener, keydown, stoppropagation

I have a problem with document event keydown.
When i pressed on specifics keys (1 or 2), the event keydown propagates to input child.
I used event.stopPropagate() but i doesn't work.

Here my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TEST KEYDOWN EVENT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Number of Series</label>
        <input type="number" name="nbSeries" value="10" id="nbSeries"/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressed);

        function keyPressed(e){

            e.stopPropagation();

            if(e.code == "Digit1" || e.code == "Digit2"){
                console.log('You pressed ' + e.code);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On console, when i change my input (#nbSeries) value using key 1 and 2, display :
You pressed "keyCode"...

Answer (score 1):

`stopPropagation` only stops the event from propagating - stopping other listeners later from seeing the event. That does *not* stop the default behavior of the action. For example, it doesn't stop characters from appearing when typing into an input field. To achieve that, you need `preventDefault` instead.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressed);
function keyPressed(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.code == "Digit1" || e.code == "Digit2") {
    console.log('You pressed ' + e.code);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Number of Series</label>
  <input type="number" name="nbSeries" value="10" id="nbSeries" />
</form>
```

---

Also, although it's not directly related to the problem you were experiencing, there's also something to keep in mind about how event propagation works. Listeners trigger in this order:

- The topmost element (the window), capturing phase
- The document, capturing phase
- Ancestors of the target, capturing phase, descending towards the target, capturing phase
- The target
- Ancestors of the target, bubbling phase
- ...

Since your document keydown listener is listening for bubbling events, it triggers only after the event's reached the target's listeners. *If* you were trying to have a listener on the document stop a listener on a child element from triggering, you would need to add the document listener in the capturing phase instead to prevent propagation downwards to the target, which can be done by passing `true` to `addEventListener`'s third parameter.